# Mysql 4 vs Mysql 5 auto-increment field on insert

Tags: mysql, database, insert, null

I've learned this along the way but can't figure out where I read it or heard it, as there is nothing I have found online supporting it, but I remember that when upgrading from mysql4.x to mysql5.x, one of the required changes was that the auto-increment field for inserts had to change from '' to NULL if it was included.

I know its not required to have in the insert anyway, but just for point of interest...

Mysql 4.x would allow:
INSERT INTO TABLE (table_id, name, location) VALUES ('', 'john', 'NY');

But mysql 5.x had to have:
INSERT INTO TABLE (table_id, name, location) VALUES (**NULL**, 'john', 'NY');

I can't find any information on mysql's site to support this, but I know for a fact it throws an error in mysql 5.x and know it worked with '' in 4.x, but where is this documented?

Comment: I have always used 0 or NULL. I didn't realize '' was valid.

Comment: What is wrong with using `null` instead of empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [4.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) and [5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) docs state that 0 or NULL is required:

> No value was specified for the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers
>   automatically. You can also explicitly
>   assign NULL or 0 to the column to
>   generate sequence numbers.

Comment: Right.. but I'm saying that 4.x was lax in the strict policy and would allow '' and I remember old code like zen-cart and websitebaker always used '' for the autoinc field. Then when 5.x came out, we had to go back and update all the code to use NULL instead of ''. But I'm trying to find where this was documented.

Comment: ok I see you linked it above and I do see the 0 or null thing.. maybe it was mysql 4.0 then.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter, mysql internally still convert to integer

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE some_test ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, primary key(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into some_test values ('');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                              |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value adjusted for column 'id' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from some_test;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, I will suggest use 0 to avoid this warning